# how to split the string and store it in to variable?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string.Now i want to split the string and store in to variable.

String:
http://cyberhawk.in/RechareApiResponse?mytxid=&txid=&optxid=&transtype=s&channel=&name=

i want to store  into TXNID,  into TXID,  into OPTXID, s in to STATUS

So please give me the way how to perform this.

Comment: `String.Split` leaps to mind.  Though since you're dealing with a query string, I believe there's a better functionality for query strings specifically in the .NET framework, though the details escape me at the moment.  Try Google.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
  Dim queryString As String = New Uri(urlString).Query()
  Dim qscoll As  = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring)
```

Edit:
You've to add the reference of System.Web if project template type is Console or WinForm.

Comment: Note that you have to switch from `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.NET Framework 4` in the advanced compiler settings, otherwise you cannot add a refernce to `System.Web`.